# Using group by on DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns as Name, Date1, Date2. I want to group count the no of people grouping by 
diffdate.

My query is

```
Select DATEDIFF( DAY, Date2, Date1) as diffdate, count(*)
from Table
group by DATEDIFF( DAY, Date2, Date1);
```

error:

> Msg 144, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Your error refers to line 8. Your code only has 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you are using SQL Server and intend:

```
Select DATEDIFF(DAY, Date2, Date1) as diffdate, count(*)
from Table
group by DATEDIFF(DAY, Date2, Date1)
order by diffdate;
```